# C# FileStream reads bytes incorrectly

Tags: c#, filestream

I am trying to develop an app that will upload large files to a web server running PHP. Almost immediately, I stumbled upon a problem that the file is not split correctly.

Currently I have this piece of code

```
string adrese = "c:\\directory\\file.jpg";
int garums = 16384;
String ext = Path.GetExtension(adrese);

FileStream file = /*/File.Open(adrese, FileMode.Open);/*/
    new FileStream(adrese, FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
long fgar = file.Length; //100%
long counter = garums;
first = true;
byte[] chunk = new byte[garums];

while (true)
{
    int index = 0;
    //long Controll = counter+garums;
    while (index < chunk.Length)
    {
        int bytesRead = file.Read(chunk, index, chunk.Length - index);
        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            /*byte[] biti = new byte[index];
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {
                biti[i] = chunk[i];
            }
            chunk = new byte[index];
            chunk = biti;*/
            break;
        }
        index += bytesRead;
    }

    if (index != 0) // Our previous chunk may have been the last one
    {
        byte[] biti = new byte[index];
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            biti[i] = chunk[i];
        }
        chunk = new byte[index];
        chunk = biti;
        // index is the number of bytes in the chunk
        sutam(Convert.ToBase64String(chunk),ext);
    }

    double procentuali = ((counter * 100) / fgar);
    if (procentuali > 99)
    {
        procentuali = 100;
    }

    progressBar1.Value = (int)Math.Round(procentuali);
    label1.Text = "" + procentuali;

    counter = counter+garums;
    if (index != garums) // We didn't read a full chunk: we're done
    {
        return;
    }
}

file.Close();
```

Everything works if I set `garums` to 1, but who will wait for a year or so to upload a file sized multiple GB's.

I would be pleased if you could tell me what is wrong and how to fix this.

Comment: for spliting file you can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967541/how-to-split-large-files-efficiently

Comment: Parameter 3 of FileStream::Read is the byte count.  You've got it as the length of the array minus your current index.  Shouldn't it be just the length of the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead to upload in chunks:

```
private void ConvertToChunks()  
{
    //Open file
    string file = MapPath("~/temp/1.xps");
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    //Chunk size that will be sent to Server
    int chunkSize = 1024;
    // Unique file name
    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file);
    int totalChunks = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)fileStream.Length / chunkSize);
    // Loop through the whole stream and send it chunk by chunk;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalChunks; i++)
    {
        int startIndex = i * chunkSize;
        int endIndex = (int)(startIndex + chunkSize > fileStream.Length ?   fileStream.Length : startIndex + chunkSize);
        int length = endIndex - startIndex;

        byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
        fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        ChunkRequest(fileName, bytes);
    }
}

private void ChunkRequest(string fileName,byte[] buffer)  
{  
    //Request url, Method=post Length and data.
    string requestURL = "http://localhost:63654/hello.ashx";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestURL);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    // Chunk(buffer) is converted to Base64 string that will be convert to Bytes on  the handler.
    string requestParameters = @"fileName=" + fileName + "&data=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode( Convert.ToBase64String(buffer) );

    // finally whole request will be converted to bytes that will be transferred to HttpHandler
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestParameters);

    request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

    Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream();
    writer.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
    writer.Close();
    // here we will receive the response from HttpHandler
    StreamReader stIn = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    string strResponse = stIn.ReadToEnd();
    stIn.Close();
}
```