# Comma in variable initialization/declaration

Tags: c#, variables, variable-declaration

I've stumbled upon a piece of code that look as follows:

```
    void check()
    {
        int integer = 7;

        //integer2 is not declared anywhere
        int check = integer, integer2;

        //after running
        //check = 7
        //integer = 7
        //integer2 = 0
    }
```

what's the purpose of the comma here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Comma on variable declarations simply allows you to declare a second variable of the same type. It is equivalent to:

```
int check = integer;
int integer2;
```

As for:

```
//integer2 is not declared anywhere
```

Yes it is; right here! This ***is*** the declaration of `integer2`.

Comment: I knew I can do this: `int integer1, integer2, integer3;` but not that this can be used both for declaration and initialization. Doesn't look like a feature id like to use since it might be misleading... Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Yoav actually, I use it lots; a classic usage is in stream IO: `int offset = 0, count; while((count = source.Read(buffer, offset, buffer.Length)) > 0) { offset += count; ... }`

Comment: surprisingly (or not) the place I originally ran into this code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3967595/1092181

Comment: @Yoav see, I told you I used it ;p